# I am getting HttpResponse but responce.getEntity().getContent() shows NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, http

```
protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
    String url = urls[0];
    String result = "";

    HttpResponse response = doResponse(url);

    if (response == null) {
        return result;
    } else {

        try {
            result = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent());

        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
        }

    }

    return result;
}
```

I am going to post data into database here below i attached my remaining codes so please check and clear my problem please

```
private HttpResponse doResponse(String url) {

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(getHttpParams());

    HttpResponse response = null;

    try {
        switch (taskType) {

        case POST_TASK:
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
            // Add parameters
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
            response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            break;
        case GET_TASK:
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
            response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            break;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

        Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);

    }

    return response;
}

private String inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {

    String line = "";
    StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();

    // Wrap a BufferedReader around the InputStream
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

    try {
        // Read response until the end
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            total.append(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
    }

    // Return full string
    return total.toString();
}
```

I am getting `NullPointerException` at following line,

`result = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent());`.

I don't understand about entity and content.anyone can help me??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your HTTP response has no entity. That is why `getEntity()` is returning `null`.

The JavaDoc for [getEntity()](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-4.3.x/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpResponse.html#getEntity%28%29) states that a `null` value can be returned. Therefore, you should always check for that.

For example, instead of:

```
result = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent());
```

you can do this:

```
final HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
if (entity == null) {
    Log.w(TAG, "The response has no entity.");

    //  NOTE: this method will return "" in this case, so we must check for that in onPostExecute().

    // Do whatever is necessary here...
} else {
    result = inputStreamToString(entity.getContent());
}
```

Comment: #cybersam thanks for your answer.but can you tell how to check that.because i am new this.can you clarify me?

Comment: #cybersam thank you brother.but i already set value for Entity.then i don't know why i don't have entity Value :( now above i updated my coding.can you clarify me?

Comment: doResponse() sets the entity in a *request*, and then returns the *response*. It is the response that has no entity.

Comment: Thank you brother i have cleared because of your teaching.thanks a lot :) and also i understand about that.thanks a lot :)